# Rails. How to create associations through categories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to setup models associations. I'm trying to add association for Menu model, to get victuals with specified category. Somehow I did it, but that's not the best way for sure. How can I improve it?
Here's my rails models:

```
class Menu < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_items
  has_many :menu_items
  has_many :victuals, through: :menu_items
  has_many :categories, through: :victuals
  # Categories in menu
  has_many :first_courses, -> { where category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'first_courses') },
                                                       through: :menu_items, source: :victual
end

class Victual < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end

class MenuItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :menu
  belongs_to :victual
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :victuals, validate: true
end
```

And db schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_06_11_172752) do

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_categories_on_name", unique: true
  end

  create_table "menu_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "menu_id"
    t.integer "victual_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["menu_id"], name: "index_menu_items_on_menu_id"
    t.index ["victual_id"], name: "index_menu_items_on_victual_id"
  end

  create_table "menus", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", default: "noname_menu"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "victuals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.decimal "price"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_victuals_on_category_id"
  end

end
```

What i get

```
irb(main):034:0> Menu.first.first_courses
  Menu Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "menus".* FROM "menus" ORDER BY "menus"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["name", "first_courses"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["name", "first_courses"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Victual Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "victuals".* FROM "victuals" INNER JOIN "menu_items" ON "victuals"."id" = "menu_items"."victual_id" 
WHERE "menu_items"."menu_id" = ? AND "victuals"."category_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["menu_id", 1], ["category_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
    => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

So, the questions are: Why are there two same Category loads?
                       Why is there [LIMIT, 11] in last query?

Comment: have you tried this? `has_many :first_courses, -> { where category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'first_courses').id }, through: :menu_items, source: :victual`

Comment: I have not tried this. Unfortunatelly i can't try it, because i made certain changes in project. For now there are many to many association between categories and victuals. So i did it through joins table, and where in string version.

Answer (score 0):

As [cmramseyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3816367/cmramseyer) said, all i needed to add id to the category instance.

```
category = Category.find_by(name: 'first_courses')
has_many :first_courses, -> { where category_id: category.id }, through: :menu_items
```

And if you want to create association many-to-many, you should do something like this:

```
class Menu < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_items
  has_many :menu_items
  has_many :victuals, through: :menu_items
  has_many :categories, through: :victuals

  def first_courses
    category = Category.find_by(name: 'first_courses')
    victuals.joins(:categories).where("categories.id = ?", category.id)
  end
end

class Victual < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end

class MenuItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :menu
  belongs_to :victual
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :victuals, validate: true
end
```